# when swiping from bottom of screen, taskbar should be visible - UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am developing an app which has a taskbar like stackpanel, in which, when I swipe from bottom of screen the taskbar stackpanel must come from below the screen, like in apple ipads, please help me, huge thanks in advance.

Comment: Your recent question was deleted before I got to comment on it. To understand how this site works, please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance around what downvoting and closing a question means and why we have these mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when swiping from bottom of screen, taskbar should be visible - UWP

For your requirement, you need detect the *taskbar*'s `ManipulationDelta` event, and if Cumulative.Translation.Y more than your threshold then invoke double animation to move taskbar down or up.

**For example**

```
private bool _isSwiped;
private void StackPanel_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsInertial && !_isSwiped)
    {
        var swipedDistance = e.Cumulative.Translation.Y;

        if (Math.Abs(swipedDistance) <= 2) return;

        if (swipedDistance > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("down Swiped");
            DownAnimiation.Begin();
        }
        else
        {
            UpAnimation.Begin();
            Debug.WriteLine("up Swiped");            
        }
        _isSwiped = true;
    }
}

private void StackPanel_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _isSwiped = false;
}
```

**Xaml Code**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="DownAnimiation">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="BottomPanel"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                To="93"
                Duration="0:0:0.5">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <BackEase />
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="UpAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="BottomPanel"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                To="0"
                Duration="0:0:0.5">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <BackEase />
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel
        x:Name="BottomPanel"
        Height="95"
        Margin="5"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Background="PaleGreen"
        CornerRadius="5"
        ManipulationCompleted="StackPanel_ManipulationCompleted"
        ManipulationDelta="StackPanel_ManipulationDelta"
        ManipulationMode="TranslateY,TranslateInertia,System">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform />
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It looks you have not described your question clearly, you could try to add some  image or screenshot.